# What is the SQLite query to exclude these items from my search?

Tags: sqlite

This is a question coming from a beginner, so thank you in advance for your patience.

The primary query is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Slovník
WHERE Note like '%' || char(13) || char(10) || '%'
```

So I want to list all entries that contain line breaks in the column Note and the above query works. However, I'd like to exclude entries that contain %(geogr.)% AND %(zool.)% from my search. 
I thought if I simply combined the above query with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Slovník
WHERE Note NOT LIKE '%(geogr.)%', '%(zool.)%'
```

that this would do the trick, but wouldn't you know, I got errors..

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `AND` operator to combine the conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Slovník
WHERE (Note like '%' || char(13) || char(10) || '%')
      AND (Note NOT LIKE '%(geogr.)%') 
      AND (Note NOT LIKE '%(zool.)%')
```

Comment: That's it, that works as expected, Thank you so much